# Supporting multiple screens in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

My issue is that I could come up with how to support multiple screens in Android. I've read many many times the android documentation and many blogs and articles:

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
2. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-design-tutorials/how-to-get-started-in-android-app-design/
3. http://www.androidhive.info/

and yet I can't even decide how to make a background image to fit most of the screens

- small
- normal
- large
- xlarge

with the dentisies:

- ldpi
- mdpi
- hdpi
- xdpi

Comment: I'd start by reconsidering having a full-screen background image.

Comment: @CommonsWare,  yes this is what I wanted to do, but can't find a way to do it :(

Comment: Agree with @CommonsWare, you should consider using simple colors for the background. Another options are using shapes, gradients, or 9-patch drawables.

Comment: @Egor I don't want to make colored BG, I have a nice designed image I wish to use in the background, the 9-patch might be handy, do you have any additions to this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, its not a recommended approach to use full screen images as backgrounds because it might cause memory issue. Even though if someone needs to use full screen image as background, there are following ways to scale it:

- Use Image with largest supported dimension
- Keep it in center and add a colored/gradient border around it
- Can stretch it to full screen (aspect ratio will not be maintained)

For in depth discussion read:

http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/11/20/tips-for-designers-from-a-developer/